# Speaker not working during calls on Android 11

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, voip, android-audiomanager

**Problem:**

I'm trying to enable speaker during a call, but the below code only works on Android 8,9 and Android 10. And in devices with Android 11, doesn't work.

Does anyone know a solution that works on Android 11?

**Code:**

```
private fun enableSpeaker() {
        audioManager?.let {
            if (!it.isSpeakerphoneOn) {
                audioManager!!.mode = AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL
                audioManager!!.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
                audioManager!!.isSpeakerphoneOn = true
            }
        }

    }

    private fun disableSpeaker() {
        audioManager?.let {
            if (it.isSpeakerphoneOn) {
                audioManager!!.mode = AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL
                audioManager!!.isSpeakerphoneOn = false
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: pls someone can help me? :(

Comment: Did you found solution for this ?

Comment: No, I searched a lot of android forums including issue tracker and nowhere is there any solution for this problem.